# Clone GCP Notebook in another Zone

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I would like to clone a GCP Vertex AI notebook in a different availability zone. The zone the notebook was created in has not been available for several days! I can't find a way to do this from the User Managed Notebook interface. So I created a clone of the notebook's VM in the Compute Engine interface, but then I don't have a url proxy to access Jupyter Lab.

Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 1):

When you say "The zone the notebook was created has not been available for several days", sounds very alarming and probably inaccurate because that would mean a disk or compute level a GCP zone is down (Does not show any related alert https://status.cloud.google.com/index.html and I don't see this in our Monitoring systems)

Notebooks VM is composed of 2 disks, boot disk and data disk which is a mount to `/home/jupyter` folder. Disks can't be moved to a different zone.
I would suggest you to create a new Notebook and copy the files. Documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/migrate